# How to set Date in JQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

Using JQuery, I want to load startDate in DatePicker.

$('#myId').datepicker({
        minDate: '-100D',
        maxDate: '+145D',
        startDate: new Date(2011,0,4)
    });

where myId is an input field. MinDate, maxDate both are working fine but startDate is not working. Currently, it is showing today's date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for [defaultDate](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker#option-defaultDate), and this is actually [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/), not just jQuery.

**Example:**

```
$('#myId').datepicker({ minDate: '-100D', maxDate: '+145D', defaultDate: new Date(2011,0,4) });
```

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't look like `startDate` is an option for the jqueryUI date picker: [Datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/) (Click options tab). I think you want `defaultDate`

Answer (score 1):

The property yo uare trying to set is actually called 'defaultDate' not 'startDate'. Also, keep in mind, that 'defaultDate' should be in range (minDate, maxDate).